# SQL Error Message

Tags: sql

Why do I get an error saying that the `SQL command is not properly ended` when I have this code:

```
SELECT MATERIALID, 
       MATERIALNAME, 
       MATERIALTYPEID, 
       CURECODEID, 
       COMBINATIONCODE, 
       MATERIALSTATUSID, 
       ACTIVATED, 
       DEACTIVATED 
FROM   MATERIAL_HEADER 
WHERE  MATERIALID = 112, 
       MATERIALNAME = 3, 
       MATERIALTYPEID = 2, 
       CURECODEID = 0, 
       COMBINATIONCODE = 3, 
       MATERIALSTATUSID = 3;
```

I've tried not including the semicolon, parenthesis and some other stuff but none has worked.

Comment: Why are your WHERE statement parts comma separated? They should be separated with logical operators, - in your case, I suspect you want AND.
E.g. `WHERE MATERIALID = 112 AND MATERIALNAME = 3 AND ...`

Comment: You have to use AND at the end, not commas.

Comment: I didn't realize they werent csv, thank you

Comment: Why the downvotes? This may be a 'simple' question but it fits the SO requirements.

Comment: @JanDoggen yeah, everyone! Calm down!

Comment: It fits in that it's a valid question, but I guess people don't like answering things that can be solved by the first dozen Google results for "how to write SQL query". Any SQL how-to will tell you that `WHERE` clauses are separated by logical operators and not commas.

Comment: @JanDoggen I agree, upvoted. It may be a simple question but it clearly states the problem, and demonstrates effort.

Comment: @anaximander I hope you are adult , Were you born adult ?You never stumbled or fall or crawled ??My motto here is do not discourage people from asking questions no matter how foolish it is .

Comment: @surajsingh I'm not discouraging the asking of questions; I'm encouraging people to try to find their own answers first. Like adults do.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try

```
SELECT MATERIALID, MATERIALNAME, MATERIALTYPEID, CURECODEID, COMBINATIONCODE, MATERIALSTATUSID, ACTIVATED, DEACTIVATED 
FROM MATERIAL_HEADER 
WHERE MATERIALID = 112 AND MATERIALNAME = 3 AND MATERIALTYPEID = 2 AND CURECODEID = 0 AND COMBINATIONCODE = 3 AND MATERIALSTATUSID = 3;
```

AND instead of ,

Comment: I didnt know they werent csv. Thank you!

Comment: not a problem! One neat thing about SQL is it's designed to read kind of like English: "Select these columns, separated by commas like in English, from this table where this thing and this thing and this thing (are true)"

Comment: Oh, and for all of you late to the party, I'd prettied up OP's original query a bit. It was all on one line.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT MATERIALID, 
       MATERIALNAME, 
       MATERIALTYPEID, 
       CURECODEID, 
       COMBINATIONCODE, 
       MATERIALSTATUSID, 
       ACTIVATED, 
       DEACTIVATED 
FROM   MATERIAL_HEADER 
WHERE  MATERIALID = 112 AND
       MATERIALNAME = 3 AND
       MATERIALTYPEID = 2 AND
       CURECODEID = 0 AND
       COMBINATIONCODE = 3 AND
       MATERIALSTATUSID = 3
```

Comment: You had some additional text in your first answer iteration; would you mind adding an explanation on why you answered as such?

Comment: @ChrisForrence To be honest it was not clear which DB engine was that. So i made it clear that my answer was for SQL Server. I don't know of all the DB engines out there, and there might be one that accepted commas as boolean operators....Though I highly doubt it.

Comment: That's definitely fair enough, and I agree that it'd be highly unlikely that a database engine accepts commas for boolean operators. However, I would suggest re-adding your "answer-is-specifically-for-sql-server-but-may-also-apply-to-other-db-servers", if so that your answer is not simply just code.

Comment: @ChrisForrence Would it really matter, since there is already an accepted answer?

Comment: As of right now, probably not. And dang, you've had a busy month!

Comment: @Chris Hehe, i just joinned and i am eager to rise. I come from EE.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, it's always best to format your queries with readable indentation;

Secondly, I think you are having the issue as your SQL script is incorrect (the where clause needs to be with *AND*.)

i.e.

```sql
SELECT MATERIALID, MATERIALNAME, MATERIALTYPEID, CURECODEID, COMBINATIONCODE,         
MATERIALSTATUSID, ACTIVATED, DEACTIVATED 
FROM MATERIAL_HEADER 
WHERE MATERIALID = 112 AND MATERIALNAME = 3 AND MATERIALTYPEID = 2 AND CURECODEID = 0 AND 
COMBINATIONCODE = 3 AND MATERIALSTATUSID = 3;
```